# Spinner can't actually not resolve to Double

Tags: java, casting, integer, double, spinner

I've copy/paste code from a laptop to another one and something goes wrong with my spinners :

So in my Controller I've that :

```
@FXML
private Spinner<Double> widthSpinner;
```

And in fxml

```
<Spinner fx:id="sp2" min="0" max="20"></Spinner>
```

It was working this morning and now I've got errors :
`java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Even a `System.out.println("__:" + widthSpinner.getValue());` is not giving me the error, so I'm clearly disappointed because it's not a problem of cast for where the value is needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix :  just change one of the following value:`startValue`, `minValue`, `MaxValue`  from `int` to `double` into the `.fxml` file

```
<Spinner fx:id="sp2" min="0" max="20"></Spinner>
```

need to becomes

```
<Spinner fx:id="sp2" min="0" max="20.0"></Spinner>
                                    ^^
```

Apparently comming from an error in my jdk version but easy to fix in the code

Answer (score 0):

The ways to initialize a Spinner are :

```
public Spinner(double min,
               double max,
               double initialValue)
```

or

```
public Spinner(double min,
               double max,
               double initialValue,
               double amountToStepBy)
```

or

```
new Spinner(SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory)
```

and to read just use widthSpinner.getValue() which will give you double value.

Spinner class has Integer and String as its common types ( probably being initialized by default).

Let me know if this helps.
Reference: [Spinner class documenation on Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html)

Comment: There is on no need to initialize elements like spinner, there are in the .fxml file, and just declared as attributes of the Controller
And the problem is not comming from here because it WAS working this morning but on another computer